# Fail Safe for circuit, when input is removed

Tags: transistors, design, driver

I have built a circuit which inverts the signal of a [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf), it is in turn connected to a relay. It is possible for the ULN2003A output to be disconnected from the external circuit as it is remote from the driver. I have tried different methods to try and make it that the circuit defaults to an off state, making the relay go to NC, yet retain normal operation.

I have been trying to work out he circuit for the whole day, to no avail. I have been trying to keep the circuit as simple as possible in that I want to use transistors.

My current circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhWlih.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the driver is active it switches the relay to NC.

The way in which it is supposed to operate is that while the driver is active the relay is contacts are NC, when the driver is OFF it should activate. Then the important part, if the driver line is removed it should then default to NC.

The last part is what has been troublesome, I need help in figuring out the circuit to achieve that.

I have also noted 0.6V on the *`ULN2003A pins`* when its is attached to the circuit, or not.

Comment: What is the 100k resistor included for? How about a pull-down resistor at the base of Q1?

Comment: It is connected to an open-collector, so without the resistor Q1 would never turn on. But the value is a bit high for my taste, I would choose ~ 1k.

Comment: With 1k, and being directly connected to ULN it never changes state

Comment: This schematic is unnecessarily obfuscated.  Put the 12 V rail across the top as one line. The bulb looping up and then crossing back over its own power connection is downright silly.  Since you at least drew a (eventually) understandable schematic, I'll give you a little time to fix it before -1.

Comment: Right, with 1 kOhm it's understandable it won't ever change state because the ULN has darlington open collector outputs, which don't go low enough to turn off Q1. The ULN is really not a good choice here.

Comment: Using the ULN is not my choice, I had to make something to work of a Chinese thing, and I changed the schematic for you Olin

Comment: Why don't you just connect the relay (with diode) to the +12V and the ULN output?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - I am not connecting it directly because I need to manipulate the signal and add redundancy to something where I have no control over the firmware where the ULN is from

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is not possible.  The datasheet shows the ULN2003A to have open collector outputs.  That means it only switches between open and actively driven low.  Open is the same as disconnected.  Your circuit therefore can't tell the difference between open and disconnected.

To make this work, you need the off state to be when the ULN is open, and active when it is pulling low.  That way, disconnected will cause off, not active.

The ULN does have some diodes connected to the output in addition to the open collector.  With more circuitry and some cleverness you could detect the presence of one of the diodes.  However, that's quite a kludge around a fundamentally bad architecture.  It is better to fix the real problem instead of kludging around it.

Comment: I noted that there is a stray 0.6V from the ULN, which in my mind I could use to detect if the driver was completely removed

Comment: @RSM: It is a loosing battle trying to fix this fundamentally bad architecture.

Comment: as I noted, I am using the bad design to my advantage, if the .6V is there I am sure it won't be when its disconnected ?